# meaning of "the sentence had been pronounced by Journey"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> In A Fine Mess, the pamphlet of the defeat that is so hard for us, one finds at the end a few heartfelt but precise pages on education and what can be done for children whose hearts are still not rotten. One is sometimes stunned by his freshness. But it is already there in Journey. “So he must love something, there is less risk with children than men, at least we have the excuse to hope that they will not turn out to be swine like us . . .  It is never that sad when an adult passes away, it’s always a cow under the earth, as they say, while a child is still less certain. There in the future.” The future is not certain, of course. But there is hope, which is the most seductive form of life.
>   We love to discover future catastrophes in this writer, who has so often prophesied evils to come with an implacable precision. **A few years before the crushing defeat struck the world in which we live, the sentence had been pronounced by Journey**. There is historical importance, like that of Dangerous Liaisons, on another plane, **which pronounced the sentence on the aristocratic society that the Revolution would decapitate**. But historical importance has never been enough to effectively insure the destiny of a book.

I really don't have any idea what is the meaning of two phrase I have bolded.

Source: https://www.counter-currents.com/2013/05/celines-journey-to-the-end-of-the-night/

Thanks before hand for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To [pronounce](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/pronounce) can mean "Declare or announce in a formal or solemn way". 
A man who has been shot may be pronounced dead by the police. His attacker may later appear in court and at the end of the trial the judge might pronounce his verdict and pronounce sentence: he might impose a prison sentence or pronounce the death sentence.

He says, *Dangerous Liaisons condemned aristocratic society to death*. More prosaically,  Céline *prophesied* its death: Robert Brasillach is, I think, exaggerating to make his point, as he is a few lines before. I can't tell what the 'crushing defeat' refers to, but whatever it is, Céline seems to have prophesied it, pronouncing sentence a few years earlier.